# Virtual machine snapshot fails, followed by a hung server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-vsphere, sql-server-2012

We've had a rather annoying incident yesterday.
During a routine snapshot backup, a machine failed with the following error:

```
Backup virtual machine
Cannot complete the operation. See the event log for details.
Incremental Forever - Incremental
```

Followed by:

```
Create virtual machine snapshot
An error occurred while saving the snapshot: msg.snapshot.error-QUIESCINGERROR.
```

Eight hours later, the next backup and snapshot kicked in, and succeeded.
However, the machine itself was completely unresponsive, and the SQL Server that was installed on it was throwing I/O errors.

On the machine itself the following warning occurred every 30 seconds for the next 12 hours:

```
Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.
```

The SQL Server, when attempting to execute any query on the databases gave the following error:

```
Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page
```

And in the SQL Logs we could find the following error:

```
SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file
```

We ended up trying to remount the databases, restart the services (SQL Server and Virtual Disk services). But in the end the only solution was a restart of the server.

What happens during the VSphere Snapshot process that could cause this chain of events?
If this is related to the VSphere Snapshot, why would a reboot fix it?

Comment: What is the data store backing the VM? Local/NAS/SAN? This sounds like the storage dropped out from under the VM

Comment: I went and investigated this as well before posting here. The backend is a SAN, on the VSPhere it is set as a datastore cluster, with the specific datastore this server was on hosting the disks for two other servers. The other servers are an app and an Oracle server. I checked there and neither server had outages, with Oracle having a clear chart of I/O statistics throughout the period, showing nothing wrong. I took this as meaning that the storage didn't drop out.